ElasticSearch - Elastic\Elasticsearch\Exception\ClientResponseException
Ive implemented ElasticSearch in our organization application and all went well so far, but when I tried to add conditions to the query it started throw 400s on almost everything I try following their documentation.
My struggle is to query for only products with status 'active'.
Here is a code snippet.
       $products = $this->elasticsearch->search([
            'index' => $product->getSearchIndex(),
            'type' => $product->getSearchType(),
            'body' => [
                '_source' => ['category_id', 'title', 'status'],
                'size' => 30,
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            'multi_match' => [ // ^1 means that title field has a higher priority in search tree
                                'fields' => ['title^1'],
                                'type' => 'phrase_prefix',
                                'query' => $query,
                            ],
                            'bool' => [
                                'must' => [
                                    [
                                        'term' => ['status' => ProductStatus::ACTIVE]
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);

Here is the full exception text I get from elastic using this piece of code above.
400 Bad Request: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":170}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:170] [bool] failed to parse field [must]","caused_by":{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":170}},"status":400}

I tried using filters and so forth, but none of the instructions in docs kind of lead me to success.
What am I missing?

Your multi_match simply needs to be in its own array element
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                      [
                        'multi_match' => [ // ^1 means that title field has a higher priority in search tree
                            'fields' => ['title^1'],
                            'type' => 'phrase_prefix',
                            'query' => $query,
                        ]
                      ],
                      [
                         'term' => ['status' => ProductStatus::ACTIVE]
                      ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],

Also it would be more efficient to do it this way by moving the constraint on status in bool/filter:
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                      [
                        'multi_match' => [ // ^1 means that title field has a higher priority in search tree
                            'fields' => ['title^1'],
                            'type' => 'phrase_prefix',
                            'query' => $query,
                        ]
                      ]
                    ],
                    'filter' => [
                      [
                         'term' => ['status' => ProductStatus::ACTIVE]
                      ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],


Thanks Val, I will try a bit later today and will return back my feedback.

Actually, I just gave it a try and it worked well!
